# Can I develop a social networking Site using WordPress and its Plugins?

Tags: buddypress, social-sharing

I am completly new to WordPress. I have a requirment where I need to develop a site where people will form communities and will blog around. They will make friends and send friend request. So its much a combination of social Networking Stuff combined with Blogging Stuff. Can somebody suggest that if I should go for WordPress or look for some other option like. ELGG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the http://buddypress.org/ plugin

Comment: +1 for buddypress - it has all the facebook-style functionality of friends, statuses etc, and it's easy to set up blogs for users. [This site (CUNY academic commons)](http://commons.gc.cuny.edu/) is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mingle. I haven't used it, but it looks pretty cool and very simple. https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mingle/
http://wpmingle.com/